# Adding and removing existing edge in a graph (BOOST)?

Tags: boost, graph, graph-theory

Lets say I have an undirected graph G. Lets say I add the following

```
add_edge(1,2,G);
add_edge(1,3,G);
add_edge(0,2,G);
```

Now I lets say add this again:

```
add_edge(0,2,G);
```

Do I have two edges in my graph from 0 ---> 2 ?

What happens if I added the edge twice and I do:

```
remove_edge(0,2,G);
```

Do both the edges disappear,or do I still have one of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions depends on the definition of graph G.

The answer to the first question, according to the [boost::graph tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:choosing-graph-type), depends on which `OutEdgeList` you use in your graph definition. If you use a container that cannot represent multiple edges (such as `setS` or `hash_setS`), there will be only one edge between two vertices no matter how many times you insert it. If you use a `vectorS`, `multisetS` or similar, there will be one edge inserted for each call of `add_edge()`.

The answer to the second question, according to [the same page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) (that section of the page does not allow direct links - just search for `remove_edge`) is that all edges between the two vertices will be removed after calling that particular `remove_edge()` function. There are several other versions of `remove_edge()` (described on the same page), each with a slightly different behaviour.